# Command composition in bash

Tags: bash, xargs

So I have the equivalent of a list of files being output by another command, and it looks something like this:

```
http://somewhere.com/foo1.xml.gz
http://somewhere.com/foo2.xml.gz
...
```

I need to run the XML in each file through xmlstarlet, so I'm doing `... | xargs gzip -d | xmlstarlet ...`, except I want xmlstarlet to be called once for each line going into gzip, not on all of the xml documents appended to each other. Is it possible to `compose 'gzip -d' 'xmlstarlet ...'`, so that xargs will supply one argument to each of their composite functions?

Comment: You cannot do it in xargs when there is a pipe... well you could, but in a very clumsy way... use something like shellter answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not read your file and process each line separately in the shell? i.e.

```
fileList=/path/to/my/xmlFileList.txt
cat ${fileList} \
| while read fName ; do
   gzip -d ${fName} | xmlstartlet > ${fName}.new
done
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest +1.

Comment: Don't abuse a cat... use while read fName; do ...; done < fList ;)

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, but used cat because with some shells I seem to recall that `... done < ${fName}` (having a variable hold the inputFile) was not reliable (I think, or maybe it was something else ;-). Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Although the right answer is the one suggested by shelter (+1), here is a one-liner "*divertimento*" providing that the input is the proposed by Andrey (a `command` that generates the list of urls) :-)

```
~$ eval $(command | awk '{a=a "wget -O - "$0" | gzip -d | xmlstartlet > $(basename "$0" .gz ).new; " } END {print a}')
```

It just generates a multi command line that does `wget http://foo.xml.gz | gzip -d | xmlstartlet > $(basenname foo.xml.gz .gz).new` for each of the urls in the input; after the resulting command is evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
cat filelist | parallel 'zcat {} | xmlstarlet >{.}.out'
```

or if you want to include the fetching of urls:

```
cat urls | parallel 'wget -O - {} | zcat | xmlstarlet >{.}.out'
```

It is easy to read and you get the added benefit of having on job per CPU run in parallel. Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

If xmlstarlet can operate on stdin instead of having to pass it a filename, then:

```
some command | xargs -i -n1 sh -c 'zcat "{}" | xmlstarlet options ...'
```

The xargs option `-i` means you can use the `"{}"` placeholder to indicate where the filename should go. Use `-n 1` to indicate xargs should only one line at a time from its input.